# junction box with no voltage between conductors but 120 V between conductors and ground

Tags: neutral, ground, junction

Two 12 gauge cables meet at a junction box. The black wires are connected. The red wires are connected.  One red wire has a black electrical tape tag. There is no voltage between the red and black wires. But there's 120 V between the black wire and ground and also 120 V between the red wires and ground. One of the cables is connected to a 240V breaker. I don't know what the other cable is connect to, probably was to an appliance that no longer exists. Is this junction dangerous?

Comment: This sounds like a formerly 240V circuit that was rewired improperly, which can happen in a bunch of different ways. **Please upload a picture showing the "240V" breaker.**

Comment: is it dual breaker (two connected together

Comment: Yeah, we'll need photos.

Comment: Folks thanks for your comments. Below is a photo of the breaker. The photo doesn't show but I checked that the ground wire of the cable is correctly connected to the ground bus of the panel.

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/u3RaF8BAhJ3tLenR7

Comment: I also figured out that the circuit used to power two electric baseboard heaters each with a thermostat. During a recent renovation a wall was removed along with it's electric heater and thermostat. Today there is one heater and thermostat and they seem to function normally. There's a second junction box in the ceiling where the wall used to be. I will open the ceiling j-box soon to see if anything looks weird about the wiring there.